# How to fix "Lazy loading not working when Browser Zoom Out"?

Tags: model-view-controller, lazy-loading, kendo-listview

In my project, we are loading kendo listview on demand like we load more data on scrolling.

We are facing an issue when the user initially zooms out in the browser. In this scenario, initially loaded data are fit in the listview so the scrollbar doesn't appear and the user is not able to load more data.

Can anyone suggest what can be done in such cases?